# iOS: CoreData and Remote API synchronization pattern

Tags: ios, core-data, pagination, data-synchronization

I have such a problem.

> /movies?page=0&size=20

api endpoint that returns paginated movies

Then I want to display this movies in UITableView. So it is easy to make pagination and load next pages of movies.

But now I want to add CoreData caching functionality and Repository pattern in between. 
Something like this

MoviesRepository (to integrate both below dependencies)
MoviesDao (to access Core Data for movies)
MoviesService (to make remote api calls)

I consider to treat Core Data as single source of truth.
So MoviesRepository -> fetchMovies(page: 2, size: 10) should make something like this:

1. call MoviesDao to get [20,30) movies from CoreData
2. make request to MoviesService -> getMovies(page: 2, size: 10)
3. after getting response it should call something like MoviesDao -> syncMovies([remoteMovies])
4. then Core Data change should be detected and movies in table view should be updated (here i think about some RxSwift observable approach or other like Combine framework in feature, maybe som CoreData nofitications, or FetchResultsController?

But the most crucial thing here is this syncing CoreData with remote data, as meantime remote data could change and page 2 is not equal to the page 2 in core data and how to resolve this problem without refetching all the data.

Here is the code that i found in some tutorial but it replaces all the data not pages.

```
private func syncFilms(jsonDictionary: [[String: Any]], taskContext: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Bool {
        var successfull = false
        taskContext.performAndWait {
            let matchingEpisodeRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Film")
            let episodeIds = jsonDictionary.map { $0["episode_id"] as? Int }.compactMap { $0 }
            matchingEpisodeRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "episodeId in %@", argumentArray: [episodeIds])

            let batchDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: matchingEpisodeRequest)
            batchDeleteRequest.resultType = .resultTypeObjectIDs

            // Execute the request to de batch delete and merge the changes to viewContext, which triggers the UI update
            do {
                let batchDeleteResult = try taskContext.execute(batchDeleteRequest) as? NSBatchDeleteResult

                if let deletedObjectIDs = batchDeleteResult?.result as? [NSManagedObjectID] {
                    NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave: [NSDeletedObjectsKey: deletedObjectIDs],
                                                        into: [self.persistentContainer.viewContext])
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error)\nCould not batch delete existing records.")
                return
            }

            // Create new records.
            for filmDictionary in jsonDictionary {

                guard let film = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Film", into: taskContext) as? Film else {
                    print("Error: Failed to create a new Film object!")
                    return
                }

                do {
                    try film.update(with: filmDictionary)
                } catch {
                    print("Error: \(error)\nThe quake object will be deleted.")
                    taskContext.delete(film)
                }
            }

            // Save all the changes just made and reset the taskContext to free the cache.
            if taskContext.hasChanges {
                do {
                    try taskContext.save()
                } catch {
                    print("Error: \(error)\nCould not save Core Data context.")
                }
                taskContext.reset() // Reset the context to clean up the cache and low the memory footprint.
            }
            successfull = true
        }
        return successfull
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? It is a common pattern to use a fetchedresultscontroller with a tableview and endless loading exactly like that. There are already many tutorials out there. You would prefer to go with offset and limit arguments instead of "page". Just load whatever the next X items are.

Comment: but I want to load data from remote api and sync them (cache them ) in core data So there is no data in core data initially. Then I load given page or (offset, limit) from api and save it in core data and next time i want to get firstly this items from core data, then load given page (which could change from api) and refresh table view with new data. I think it is not possible to know which data on which page have changed.

Comment: I have replaced this approach with 2 entities in core data MovieQuery and Movie. Movie stores all currently cached movies that can participate in different MovieQuery relationships (many - to - many relationship) Then when I make fetch movie page (MovieQuery is returned from Core Data (for this page) if it exists with list of available movies, then remote api call is made to get new MovieQuery then this Movie Query is sync (saved) to Core Data, and pushed to observable as refreshed data. this why I can manage caching this pages of movies, and have Movie objects updated accordingly

Comment: this is a great question and it's astonishing there are zero answers !